# How to prove these three norm equivalence problems

Tags: normed-spaces, equivalence-relations

Given $A \in R^{m\times n}$, I have these three norm equivalence equations:

1. $\|A\|_2 \le \|A\|_F \le \sqrt {n}\|A\|_2$
2. $\frac {1} {\sqrt n}\|A\|_{\infty} \le \|A\|_2 \le \sqrt {m} \|A\|_{\infty}$
3. $\frac {1} {\sqrt m}\|A\|_1 \le \|A\|_2 \le \sqrt {n} \|A\|_1$

I cannot use the following:

$$||A||_F = \sqrt {Tr(A^TA)}$$

I need to prove each of them.  I do not even know where to begin on this so ANY help would be great!

The norms are the matrix norms.  You can find more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm.  Essentially the 1 norm is just adding up each element of a column and finding the largest column sum.  The infinity norm is the same as 1 norm except you add up the elements in a row and find the largest row sum.  The F norm (frobenius norm) is adding up the squares of each element in A and then taking the square root.

Comment: What exactly are each of these norms?

Comment: These are matrix norms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(not doing all, but here's a few)*

1. The key here is to notice that 
   $$
   \|A\|_F^2=\text{Tr}_n(A^TA).
   $$
   Then
   $$
   \|A\|_2^2=\lambda_\max(A^TA)\leq\text{Tr}_n(A^TA)\leq n\lambda_\max(A^TA),
   $$
   so $\||A\|_2\leq\|A\|_F\leq\sqrt n\|A\|_2$.
2. Here, writing $e=(1,\ldots,1)^T\in\mathbb R^n$,
   $$
   \|A\|_\infty=\max_i\sum_j|A_{ij}|=\|Ae\|_\infty\leq\|Ae\|_2\leq\|A\|_2\|e\|_2=\sqrt n\|A\|_2
   $$

Comment: I am not suppose to use that the frobenius norm is equal to the sqrt of the trace.  I should of stated that, sorry!